# Failed to parse QName

Tags: xml

When I do a syntax check on the following XML code I get the error:

error on line 2 at column 14: Failed to parse QName 'xmlns:'

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<Bitmap xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android: src = "@ assets/dragon.png" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Infact you could have tried this yourself

XML does not allow white-space characters in element- or attribute-names.

Remove the space between `xmlns:` and `android` ; Also `android:` and `src`

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<Bitmap xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src = "@ assets/dragon.png" />
```

I tried using online validator, and dont see errors now 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Update: As **@Ian Roberts** suggested, Please use this validator. I tried this, it was showing all possible warnings as well - http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: :) np..Please feel free to  accept as answer, thanks

Comment: If you're going to recommend an online validator then I'd go with http://validator.w3.org (the people responsible for the standards) rather than w3schools (nothing to do with the W3C, just a business using the w3 name to make money selling unaccredited qualifications).

Comment: Thanks @Superole for the edit on "XML does not allow white-space characters ", but I don't agree with your edit comment.